# what does the @d mean in ''xterm -display @d'

Tags: batch-file, xterm

An existing .bat script running on Windows XP has a call to xterm with the flag '-display @d'. I need to alter the display value being passed through to xterm, to point to a different IP address. However, it would help to know what the @d currently stands for and passes in.

Answer (score 1):

`@d` is an Exceed specific variable.

Your hostname will get substituted for the `@d` along with a `:0.0`

If you want to alter the value of @d you can just remove it and replace it with whatever hostname or IP address you want.

Comment: Is there a way of printing out the @d?

Comment: so, just replace @d with whatever IP you want.